# MongoDB Java Driver @BsonDiscriminator not working

Tags: java, mongodb, discriminator

I am trying to write and read a complex object to a MongoDB using Java Mongo Driver.

The object includes among other things Lists of Objects of different but related type that I cover with abstract classes in the data model, for example:

```
public class Datatypes{
    public List<DatatypeDefinitionTag> datatypeDefinitions;
}
```

...which gets filled with these objects:

```
public class DatatypeDefinitionInteger extends DatatypeDefinitionTag {
    [...]
}

public class DatatypeDefinitionString extends DatatypeDefinitionTag {
    [...]
}
```

Now, according to the documentation (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/bson/pojos/#properties-with-abstract-or-interface-types) this should work by annotating the abstract class as follows:

```
@BsonDiscriminator
public abstract class DatatypeDefinitionTag {
    [...]
}
```

...however, if I do that, I still get an error while trying to read data from the MongoDB, and checking the MongoDB directly, I can see that all entries under `datatypeDefinitions` have `_t:reqIF.reqIF_dataStructure.abstracts.tags.DatatypeDefinitionTag`

I would have expected the discriminator to assign the following values instead, based on the saved object:

- `_t:reqIF.reqIF_dataStructure.coreContent.reqIF_content.datatypes.datatypeDefinitions.DatatypeDefinitionString`
- `_t:reqIF.reqIF_dataStructure.coreContent.reqIF_content.datatypes.datatypeDefinitions.DatatypeDefinitionInteger`

Any idea why this is happening? In essence, I am just looking for the Java equivalent of how this would work with the .Net Driver:

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(DatatypeDefinitionString), typeof(DatatypeDefinitionInteger))]
public class DatatypeDefinitionTag
```

---

EDIT:

I have now created a minimalistic test project which replicates this behavior (run MongoDB_ReaderTest).

[MongoDB Java Driver @BsonDiscriminator not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832769/mongodb-java-driver-bsondiscriminator-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

The `@BsonDiscriminator` tag is working for abstract classes starting from the following version of MongoDB Java Driver: `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.6.0`

Once I upgraded to this version, everything started to work as intended.